# SMR shadow fade by script?

Tags: unity, shadows, skinning

I want to make fade for my player shadow. I don't know if it's possible or not. In my skinned mesh render there is "Cast shadows" with four options "Off, On, Two sides, and Shadows Only". How to do it by a script ?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what a "shadow fade" is in your context? It also sounds like you're using Unity — if that's true, please add that tag to your question.

Comment: I edit tags. I mean body shadow of player [example](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/child-casting-shadow-young-man-600w-197572088.jpg). Instead of turn On/Off shadow. I need smooth transfer that I can control it by script.

Comment: Transfer from what state to what state? What kind of effect do you ultimately want to make with this?

Comment: [Normal black shadow](https://sites.google.com/site/fxstudios99/blender-3d/blender-basics-2-5/lighting-a-cube/lighting%20a%20cube%202.png). Transfer from black to none. If you have a cube with a black shadow that's mean the "cast shadow" is ON. If you turn it to OFF you will not see a shadow from it. Now I want to make a script to make a smooth transfer between On and Off.

Comment: Do you have other shadow-casting objects in your scene? If so, this will be rather difficult - in shadow mapping, the pass that draws the lighting effects on the shadow-receiver knows little to nothing about which specific object is responsible for a particular shadow - and can't reliably distinguish cases where a shadow that should be faded overlaps with a shadow that should not.